# Databricks Job Cluster CosmosDB Jar java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

I have been following letter by letter the [Databricks Official guide](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html#example-install-postgresql-jdbc-driver) to include an init script to a Databricks Cluster(a Job Cluster, not live one), to install the [Azure CosmosDB Jar Library(PySpark 2.4)](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector.html#create-and-attach-required-libraries).

This is my init script:

```
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/cosmosdb-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash 
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-2.1.2-uber.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/microsoft/azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11/2.1.2/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-2.1.2-uber.jar""", True)
```

And I verify it exists with: `display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/databricks/scripts/cosmosdb-install.sh"))`.

Then I launch my job cluster through Azure Data Factory and when it reaches the CosmosDB Code it keeps failing with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:143)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:122)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:378)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:328)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$.<init>(UsageLogging.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$.<clinit>(UsageLogging.scala)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordUsage(UsageLogging.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.recordUsage(DatabricksMain.scala:63)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordEvent(UsageLogging.scala:699)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.recordEvent(DatabricksMain.scala:63)
    at com.databricks.DatabricksMain.main(DatabricksMain.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverDaemon.main(DriverDaemon.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    ... 12 more
```

The same code works 100% fine when tested in an interactive cluster and by installing the library through the UI buttons.

The interactive cluster I tested this code with has the same runtime version with the Job Cluster I have configured through Azure Data Factory: `6.6 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)`.

Also this is the screenshot of the Job Cluster in the Databricks Web UI:

[image: job cluster]

And this is the PySpark code:

```
df = spark.read.format(
    "com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**readConfig).load()
```

Could someone reproduce this or can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why that exception occurs when trying to install the library with the init script but I have managed to achieve my goal by configuring the "Append Libraries" option for the Databricks Notebook Activity, and then pointing to the JAR I had downloaded in advance in the DBFS in my Databricks Workspace.

[image: ADF DatabricksNotebook]